# Can Windows 8 applications run on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

The windows 8 app development tecnology sugessted is very similar to WP7 development. They both based on the Silverlight technology. So the question is from now can  we  use a single application for windows phone and windows 8 ?

Comment: Developer questions aren't on-topic for Super User. I would suggest that you do some more research though - Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 use the same underlying technology, but it's not Silverlight anymore and there's a little bit of work involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.quora.com/Will-Windows-Phone-7-or-7-5-apps-run-on-Windows-8-tablets

"Hi, Windows 8 Metro-style apps use XAML for their UI and is similar to the markup in Silverlight. The differenece is in the namespaces that the two use (ie where to get the resource for say a listbox), similarly c# is supported in Windows 8 so out of the box a precompiled WP7 app wouldn't run but a vendor can update the existing code to produce an app targeting Windows 8 Metro. Although not trivial it's not that hard involving a bit of copy/replace and some intellisense."

So in conclusion it is possible its just that some code needs to be changed as some of the resources have different locations on each OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The easiest way to achieve this effect will be to use javascript, although this isn't much different then just writing browser only applications.